# how to reset a cadence workflow with client sdk?

Tags: java, cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

i have a cadence workflow with 3 activities. Scenario. the first activity is completed while executing second, the workflow failed after retry limit reached. now the problem has been fixed. how can i restart the failed workflow.

i have read this question [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65104070/how-to-restart-a-timeouted-failed-canceled-terminated-cadence-workflow/65104071#65104071).

i want to know that how can i use reset API in java client sdk to implement it.

cadence-dependence: compile group: 'com.uber.cadence', name: 'cadence-client', version: '3.5.0'

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the WorkflowServiceTChannel class I found a method ResetWorkflowExecution. through it reset can be acheieved. code show as blow:


public void testReset(String workflowid, String runid, String completeid){

WorkflowClient workflowClient = WorkflowClient.newInstance(
new WorkflowServiceTChannel(
ClientOptions.newBuilder().setHost("127.0.0.1").setPort(8080).setFeatureFlags(new FeatureFlags().setWorkflowExecutionAlreadyCompletedErrorEnabled(true)).build()),
WorkflowClientOptions.newBuilder().setDomain("domain-test").build());

ResetWorkflowExecutionRequest request = new ResetWorkflowExecutionRequest();
WorkflowExecution workflowExecution = new WorkflowExecution();
workflowExecution.setWorkflowId(workflowid);
workflowExecution.setRunId(runid);
request.setRequestId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
request.setDomain("domain-test");
request.setDecisionFinishEventId(Long.valueOf(completeid));
request.setWorkflowExecution(workflowExecution);
try {
workflowClient.getService().ResetWorkflowExecution(request);
} catch (TException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [iWF](https://github.com/cadence-oss/iwf) for your Cadence/Temporal project:

It is serving [REST API for workflow operations](https://github.com/cadence-oss/iwf-idl/blob/main/iwf.yaml#L13). You can use [Postman/Curl](https://github.com/cadence-oss/iwf/blob/f8cb9566a1a43da249335ca600f66042e901428a/script/http/local/home.http#L19) to reset workflows.

It also has a [Java API for reset](https://github.com/cadence-oss/iwf-java-sdk/blob/35604e1b1e432e0879d2c833e1cae536edba017a/src/main/java/io/github/cadenceoss/iwf/core/Client.java#L115).

Comment: thank you for your reply. is iwf an extension of cadence/temporal?

Comment: Yes, that’s another way to look at it. It is basically providing a simplified way to use Cadence Temporal but keep the same power